# How to print a DWord in assembly?

Tags: assembly, numbers, nasm, dword

I'm learning Assembly, and it would be nice for me to be able to output a number to the screen instead of just a string of text. I know how to print a character using `mov eax, 1`, but that doesn't work with DWords.

I am using 64-bit Ubuntu.

Makefile:

```
all:
    nasm -f elf64 asm.s -o asm.o
    ld asm.o -o asm
    rm asm.o
```

Comment: The makefile will not assist anyone without seeing your code.  Show us what you've already written and specifically describe the error you are receiving and how you've tried to address it.

Comment: Hi, I don't really have any code, I just want to know how I could print out a dword instead of just an ascii string. I'm sorry for posting the makefile, I thought it would be useful for the assembler and configurations to be known. My bad.

Comment: You'd have to write a function/code that converts a number (like a dword value) to a string and then print the string with a syscall. The easier way though is to link using _GCC_, use a function `main` instead of `_start` and then cal the _C_ library functions like `printf` to print formatted text. This tutorial/code may help: https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/sample_64.shtml#printf1_64.asm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to print stuff would be just using `printf`, you're asking how to print a dword, that's easy:

```
extern _printf

SECTION .data
    msg:     db "Printing a dword: %d",10,0
    number:  dd  123456789

SECTION .text
    global start

start:
    push dword [number]
    push dword msg
    call _printf
    add esp, 8
    mov eax, 0
    ret
```